# Saving classes data to an encrypted file using ProtoBuf-Net library in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, deserialization, protobuf-net

I’m developing an application that uses ProtoBuf-Net library to save the classes data to a binary file. I would like the contents of the saved file was unreadable by humans, but when I open this binary file in Notepad++ it is possible to read the values filled in classes. What should I add to the code below in order to encrypt the classes data and make everything unreadable by humans?

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System.IO;

namespace TestProtoBufNet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person = new Person
            {
                Id = 12345,
                Name = "Fred",
                Address = new Address
                {
                    Line1 = "Flat 1",
                    Line2 = "The Meadows"
                }
            };
            using (var file = File.Create("C:\\Temp\\person.bin"))
            {
                Serializer.Serialize(file, person);
            }
        }

        [ProtoContract]
        class Person
        {
            [ProtoMember(1)]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [ProtoMember(2)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [ProtoMember(3)]
            public Address Address { get; set; }
        }

        [ProtoContract]
        class Address
        {
            [ProtoMember(1)]
            public string Line1 { get; set; }
            [ProtoMember(2)]
            public string Line2 { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Encrypt it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/encrypting-data

Comment: Protobuf is not encryption. They are completely separate things, and protobuf-net doesn't have any encryption settings for the same.reaaons that Json.NET and XmlSerializer don't have encryption settings. If you want to encrypt something, then as @TheGeneral says: *encrypt it*. But: separately. If the encryption API you're using offers a Stream API, then you can what that Stream between the FileStream and the serializer, and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @TheGeneral comment and in [this article](https://static.scaleoutsoftware.com/docs/dotnet_client/articles/serialization/crypto.html) that I've found, I could construct the following solution:

```
using ProtoBuf;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace TestProtoBufNet
{
    class Program
    {
        // IMPORTANT:
        //  This cryptographic key is defined in code for demonstration purposes.
        //  Production keys should be stored in a secure location,
        //  (such as Azure Key Vault or AWS KMS) or protected using .NET's 
        //  ProtectedData class.
        private static readonly byte[] secretKey = new byte[]
                               {
                                87, 167, 103, 151, 197, 100, 254, 130,
                                74,  59,  51,  28,  26, 230,   7,  97,
                                137, 224,  69,  23,  51, 110,   3,  37,
                                157,  41,  12,  12, 158,  24,  30,  86
                               };

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person person = new Person
            {
                Id = 12345,
                Name = "Fred",
                Address = new Address
                {
                    Line1 = "Flat 1",
                    Line2 = "The Meadows"
                }
            };

            string filePath = "C:\\Temp\\person.bin";
            CryptoSerializer<Person> cryptoSerializer = new CryptoSerializer<Person>(secretKey);

            //Write person class data to a binary file.
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                cryptoSerializer.Serialize(person, fileStream);
            }

            //Reads the binary file and displays its contents in the console.
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                Person personRead = cryptoSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);

                Console.WriteLine("Data read from " + filePath + ":");
                Console.WriteLine("\tId\t:\t" + personRead.Id);
                Console.WriteLine("\tName\t:\t" + personRead.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("\tLine1\t:\t" + personRead.Address.Line1);
                Console.WriteLine("\tLine1\t:\t" + personRead.Address.Line2);
                Console.Write("Press any key to close...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        [ProtoContract]
        class Person
        {
            [ProtoMember(1)]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [ProtoMember(2)]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [ProtoMember(3)]
            public Address Address { get; set; }
        }

        [ProtoContract]
        class Address
        {
            [ProtoMember(1)]
            public string Line1 { get; set; }
            [ProtoMember(2)]
            public string Line2 { get; set; }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializer to encrypt/decrypt objects using AES.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object to serialize/deserialize.</typeparam>
    public class CryptoSerializer<T>
    {
        private byte[] _secretKey;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="secretKey">
        /// Secret key. Legal AES keys are 16, 24, or 32 bytes long.
        /// </param>
        public CryptoSerializer(byte[] secretKey)
        {
            _secretKey = secretKey;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serialization callback that can be registered with 
        /// a cache using CacheBuilder.SetSerialization
        /// </summary>
        public void Serialize(T obj, Stream stream)
        {
            // The first 16 bytes of the serialized stream is the 
            // AES initialization vector. (An IV does not need to be
            // secret, but the same IV should never be used twice with
            // the same key.)
            byte[] iv = GenerateRandomBytes(16);
            stream.Write(iv, 0, 16);

            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aes.Key = _secretKey;
                aes.IV = iv;

                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
                                                             aes.CreateEncryptor(),
                                                             CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                // Using protobuf-net for serialization
                // (but any serializer can be used to write to this CryptoStream).
                ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(cryptoStream, obj);

                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialization callback that can be registered with 
        /// a cache using CacheBuilder.SetSerialization
        /// </summary>
        public T Deserialize(Stream stream)
        {
            // First 16 bytes is the initialization vector.
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            stream.Read(iv, 0, 16);

            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                aes.Key = _secretKey;
                aes.IV = iv;

                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
                                                             aes.CreateDecryptor(),
                                                             CryptoStreamMode.Read);

                return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(cryptoStream);
            }
        }

        // This RNG is thread safe. Used to generate IV.
        private static RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

        private static byte[] GenerateRandomBytes(int length)
        {
            byte[] randomBytes = new byte[length];
            rng.GetBytes(randomBytes);
            return randomBytes;
        }
    }
}
```